# Inhomogeneous transport equation with terminal value available

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

From [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1emgOSiNocE) video I understand that in case of the inhomogeneous transport equation $$ u_t + c u_x = g (t,x)\tag{$\ast$}$$ with initial value $u (0,x) = \tilde{h} (x)$, the solution may be written as $$u (t,x) = \tilde{h} (x - ct) + \int_0^t g(s,x + (s - t)c)\ ds.\tag{$\ast\ast$}$$

I'm looking at $(\ast)$ but I only know its terminal value $u (T, x) = h (x)$.

Question: how does $(\ast\ast)$ change?

---

UPDATE: The specific case I'm looking at is $g (t,x)=-k_1 x$ and $h (x)=k_2$ with $k_i>0$ and constant, $i\in\left\{1,2\right\}$.

Comment: could you look at $v(t,x) = u(T-t,x)$?

Comment: I have an expectation regarding the solution. If I do what you suggest (I also replace $s$ by $T - s$) and multiply $v_t$ and $c v_x$ with $-1$, I obtain that expected solution. Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$u_t+cu_x=g(t,x)$$
Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{c}=\frac{du}{g(t,x)}$$
First characteristic equation from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{c}$:
$$x-ct=C_1$$
Second characteristic equation from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{g(t,x)}=\frac{du}{g(t,(C_1+ct))}$

$$u=\int g(t,(C_1+ct))dt+\text{constant}$$
$$u=\int_0^t g(s,(C_1+cs))ds+C_2$$

The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $C_2=F(C_1)$ leads to :
$$\boxed{u(t,x)=\int_0^t g(s,(x-ct+cs))ds+F(x-ct)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to the condition $u(T,x)=h(x)$ :
$$h(x)=\int_0^T g(s,(x-cT+cs))ds+F(x-cT)$$
Change of variable : $\quad X=x-cT\quad\implies\quad x=X+cT$
$$h(X+cT)=\int_0^T g(s,(X+cs))ds+F(X)$$
$$F(X)=h(X+cT)-\int_0^T g(s,(X+cs))ds$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is known.

We put it into the above general solution where $X=x-ct$ thus $F(x-ct)=h(x-ct+cT)-\int_0^T g(s,(x-ct+cs))ds$ :

$u(t,x)=\int_0^t g(s,(x-ct+cs))ds+h(x-ct+cT)-\int_0^T g(s,(x-ct+cs))ds$

$$\boxed{u(t,x)=h(x-ct+cT)-\int_t^T g(s,(x-ct+cs))ds}$$

Of course it was possible to get the result without solving the whole from the begining to the end. One could use the known solution in the case of given initial condition and directly transforming it to the case of given final condition.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, I don't know $u (0,x)$. I used your solution with my specification of $h$ and $g$ (see update) and the result is what I expected. Thanks a lot, will digest it now.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand why you asked your question: it's because I also wrote $u (0,x)=h(x)$, right? Will update that $h$ to $\tilde{h}$, so that the difference is clear and your answer can remain as it is.

Comment: OK. I will also update my answer to delete my initial question. So all will be consistent.